# Calling a method in an "if statement" makes UIImageView move erratically

Tags: objective-c, if-statement, uiimageview, uibutton, touchesbegan

I don't know if the issue I have is something to do with execution or issue with the if statement. I have uiimageview with random image, which it picks right after appearing on the screen, animating upwards. The uiimageView animates smoothly but when I call any method or put some code in the "if statement" below, the uiimageview starts to animate erratically...wierd! confusing!. The code executes well though, but weird movements give the method called or the code a second chance, I want the uiimageview to continue moving smoothly even when I call a method.

I tried to use buttons instead of touchesBegan and UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction but the issue still persists. imageViews are in a container, so they respond based on the image displayed by the animating uiimageview.

```
if ((touch.view == self.imageView1)
    && [UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.movingRectangle1.image) isEqualToData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image_a)]
    && ([UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.imageView1.image) isEqualToData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image_b)]
        || [UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.imageView1.image) isEqualToData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image_c)]
        || [UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.imageView1.image) isEqualToData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image_d)]
        || [UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.imageView1.image) isEqualToData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image_e)]
        || [UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.imageView1.image) isEqualToData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image_f)])){

        // wierd movements happen when I call a method here
        NSLog(@"imageShape1 touched, correct view!");
    }
else if ((touch.view == self.imageView1)
         &&  ([UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.imageView1.image) isEqualToData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image_g)]
              || [UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.imageView1.image) isEqualToData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image_h)]
              || [UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.imageView1.image) isEqualToData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image_i)]
              || [UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.imageView1.image) isEqualToData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image_j)])){

             NSLog(@"touched but Wrong view!");
         }
```

Comment: This is unrelated but it would be WAY more efficient to assign tags to the image views and compare the tags instead of converting the images to PNG data over and over.

Comment: +347 to @rmaddy comment

Comment: @rmaddy: I have been trying to do that the entire time but I couldn't, I am new in Objective c, so please can you show me, using the if statement above, how I can do it using tags. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @VinsRach That's a different question from what you posted. I suggest you either redo this question specifically about getting these `if` statements working with tags or your post a separate question on that topic. Either way, be sure the question includes the code you've attempted to use with tags and explain the issue you have with it.